# Task Switcher inside VNC

Tags: window-manager, vnc

I run a VNC client (tightvnc) along with other applications on a Windows machine. Inside my VNC session, I typically have several xterms and gvim windows open. **How can I switch between the applications within VNC?** If I do ALT-TAB, that results in switching between the applications in Windows where the whole VNC is considered as a single application; I do not want that. Is there some way to configure some key bindings, any two/three keystroke is okay for me, to do the job?

Comment: This question might belong on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), this is really about keybindings in tightvnc on windows... im not going to vote for close however, rather let the community decide on this one.

Comment: @Stefan Voting to close *is* letting the community decide; you're part of the community :). I guess it depends if the solution is Windows-side or not; I don't know either though

Comment: I meant, rather let **other** people in the community decide.. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to modify the keyboard shortcut assigned to switching windows on the VNC server side desktop. You didn't specify what desktop environment you are using but on my computer (Ubuntu 10.10 with Gnome) this is the Keyboard Shortcuts control panel from the System menu (System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts).

[image: System : Preferences Menu with Keyboard Shortcuts highlighted]

The Alt-Tab function is near the bottom (under "Window Management", labelled "Move between windows, using a popup window"). Change it from Alt-Tab to something that isn't a shortcut on either your Windows computer or the apps you're using on the VNC server side.

[image: Keyboard shortcuts control panel]

Answer (score 5):

This probably does belong on SuperUser, but, here's a solution.

I use the vnc viewer from TightVNC (so, this might not work on all vnc viewers). On the tool bar at the top of the vnc viewer window there is an ALT modifier button. Click that (it should remain pressed). Then, just press tab. Once you've got the window you want, click the alt button again to un-press it.

[image: Alt-toolbar-button]

Answer (score 2):

Both the TurboVNC and TigerVNC viewers support keyboard grabbing, which will allow you to send Alt-Tab and other special keystrokes to the VNC server.  TurboVNC evolved from the TightVNC 1.3.x code base originally, so it maintains full backward compatibility with all of the TightVNC 1.3.x features (but it also has many new features and fixes relative to TightVNC 1.3.x.)  TigerVNC was based on RealVNC originally, so it does not have 100% coverage of the TightVNC features, but it and TurboVNC share similar encoding techniques.  Both implement a variant of Tight encoding that is tuned for high performance.  If you are using Windows as a client, then TurboVNC's GUI for that platform is generally nicer than TigerVNC's (the TurboVNC Windows viewer still has the same basic look & feel as the TightVNC Windows viewer.)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The asker was not looking for the history of VNC

Comment: The poster asked how to switch between applications in a remote VNC session. To do that, the VNC viewer has to pass Alt-Tab keystrokes to the VNC server. VNC viewers have to implement "keyboard grabbing" in order to intercept Alt-Tab keystrokes and pass them to the VNC server. TightVNC, which the poster said they were using, can't do that. TurboVNC, which originally derives from TightVNC and is thus compatible with it, can do that. The history was provided in the context of reassuring the poster that there was a TightVNC-compatible solution that accomplished what they wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Try Remmina! 
See there: http://www.brianodonovan.ie/2012/02/remmina-is-best-linux-application-for.html

The <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> is an example of a key combination which could be interpreted by your local operating system or by the remote operating system.

As you say, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> will by default switch focus from Remmina to another local application on your laptop. If you want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between applications on your remote Windows system then you need to select the option "grab all keyboard events" (there is an icon at the top of the Remmina screen to enable/disable this).

Answer (score 1):

I use the RealVNC viewer, this has an option "SendSpecialKeys" (default enabled) to send Alt-TAB, Windows key and some more to the VNC server.

Using different keys like in the accepted answer is very confusing and not possible if the VNC server is a Windows computer.